# How do I find with reference of a MongoDB model

Tags: mongodb, express, routes, mern

I am trying to find the ID of a model which is a reference to another model. I have a shopModel and a productModel that has a reference to shopModel

```
//shopModel
const shopSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User",
  },
name: {
    type: String,
  },
description: {
    type: String,
  }
})

//productModel
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    shop: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Shop",
    },
 name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
//and more
```

Now my question is do I use `await Product.find({ shop: "shopID"})` or `await Product.findById(req.params.id)`. The current route is `/shop/shopID`. Note that there will be multiple shops and multiple products in one shop, but no shop will have the same productID. The problem now is I tried to `console.log await Product.findById(req.params.id)` and turned up undefined. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
//current productController
const getProducts = AsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const shopID = await Product.findOne({
    shop: req.params.id,
  });
  console.log(shopID._id);
  const products = await Product.find({
    shop: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
  });
  res.json({ products });
});
```

The output log is the `product ID`

```
//new productController
const getProducts = AsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const shopID = await Shop.findOne({
    shop: req.params.id,
  });
  console.log(shopID._id);
  const products = await Product.find({
    shop: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
  });
  res.json({ products });
});
```

Now I am getting the `shop ID`. I created 2 test shops, shop1 has all the products, while shop2 has none. The current problem is the log for both shops is giving the same id.

Comment: Why are you doing `await Shop.findOne({ shop: req.params.id });` when your Shop schema does not have a shop property?

Comment: @RubekJoshi I see the error and changed it to `await Shop.findOne(req.params.id)` but the log for both shops is still giving the same id. when I use `await Shop.findById(req.params.id)` It returns null.